# Could not load library cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll. Error code 126 Please make sure cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll is in your library path

Tags: python, tensorflow, cudnn

I am quiet certain I installed everything correctly, and the required file is clearly in my path. I am not sure what I can do at this point. Please Help.

echo %path%
C:\Users\idvin\anaconda3\envs\3.7;C:\Users\idvin\anaconda3\envs\3.7\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\idvin\anaconda3\envs\3.7\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\idvin\anaconda3\envs\3.7\Library\bin;C:\Users\idvin\anaconda3\envs\3.7\Scripts;C:\Users\idvin\anaconda3\envs\3.7\bin;C:\Users\idvin\anaconda3\condabin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\libnvvp;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\iCLS;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2020b\bin;C:\Users\idvin\Downloads\elastix-4.9.0-win64;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2022.1.0;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\bin\cudnn_cnn_infer64_8.dll;D:\dll_x64\dll_x64\zlibwapi.dll;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin;C:\Users\idvin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\idvin\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.6.4\bin;D:\dll_x64\dll_x64\zlibwapi.dll;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6\bin\cudnn_cnn_train64_8.dll;.

Comment: solved it in my path i needed to add the directory of zlibwapi.dll not zlibwapi.dll itself

Answer (score 1):

solved it in my path i needed to add the directory of zlibwapi.dll not zlibwapi.dll itself